# React Router DOM can't read location state

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, state

I've seen this question before but only applied to Class components so I am not sure how to apply the same approach for functional components.

It's simple, I have a link `<Link to={{ pathname="/first-page" state: { name: "First person" }>First Page</Link>` and then in the component **FirstPage.js** I need to read the `name` state so I have tried the following:

```js
import React from "react";

export default props => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props)
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>First Page</h1>
      <p>Welcome to first page, {props.location.state.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have been reading [React Router location documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location) and it should pass the state as a component property but it isn't. I am quite sure there is something I am doing wrong or not seeing at all.

In case you wanna give a try on the whole code, I will leave here a [CodeSandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-haze-wi17h) to "test" this.

Therefore, any ideas on what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't an issue of class-based vs. functional component, but rather how Routes work. Wrapped children don't receive the route params, but anything rendered using the `Route`'s `component`, `render`, or `children` prop do.

[Route render methods](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-render-methods)

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/first-page" component={FirstPage} />
  <Route path="/second-page" component={SecondPage} />
</Switch>
```

[image: Edit pedantic-banzai-dhz27]

The other option is to export a decorated page component using the `withRouter` HOC, or if a functional component, use hooks.

[withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)

> You can get access to the `history` object’s properties and the closest
>   `<Route>`'s `match` via the `withRouter` higher-order component. `withRouter`
>   will pass updated `match`, `location`, and `history` props to the wrapped
>   component whenever it renders.

```
const FirstPage = props => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props)
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>First Page</h1>
      <p>Welcome to first page, {props.location.state.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(FirstPage);
```

[hooks](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks)

> React Router ships with a few `hooks` that let you access the state of
>   the router and perform navigation from inside your components.

```
const FirstPage = props => {
  const location = useLocation();

  console.log(location);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>First Page</h1>
      <p>Welcome to first page, {location.state.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FirstPage;
```

Comment: Anyway, I will use the `useLocation()` approach from the second answer to make use of hooks.

Comment: Ah, yes, there's also hooks for them, but I find it a little more tedious testing components using the react-router-dom hooks versus those that use the `withRouter` HOC as it's *much easier* passing mock props. I'll update answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a problem in your router. Instead of using:

```
 <Route path="/first-page">
    <FirstPage/>
 </Route>
```

Use:

```
<Route path="/first-page" component={FirstPage}/>
```

Otherwise use the hook provided by the library `let location = useLocation();`, this way you will have access to the location object.

Comment: Well, this worked fine as well. The last approach let's me use hooks so I don't need to modify all the code. Thanks